# How can i convert to a sub type of IList<T> from List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have managed to create my own IList sub class using some code i found on another thread on the MSDN. I have added some of my own methods and have tested the class in basic scenarios and it seems to be working fine.

The problem is that when i try and use the regular .ToList() method i am returned a List instead of my custom pList. Obviously i need to cast it to my new type but i am unsure how. Do i need to implement another method in my custom iList to allow it to be assigned with a different format?

My class is declared as shown below.

```
public class pList<T> : IList<T>
```

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to cast a `List<T>` directly to `pList<T>`.  You could make an extension method (just like `ToList`).  Assuming your class has a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` to populate the list:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    static pList<T> ToPList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence) { return new pList<T>(sequence); }
}
```

If your class doesn't have such a constructor, you can either add one, or do something like this:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    static pList<T> ToPList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        var result = new pList<T>();
        foreach (var item in sequence)
            result.Add(item);
        return result;
    }
}
```

> my pList class does have a constructor that takes IEnumerable have added your extension method but i am still unable to see ToPList() within the List Am i missing something?

First, if you have such a constructor, and you want to convert an existing `List<T>` to a `pList<T>`, you can of course do this:

```
List<T> originalList = GetTheListSomehow();
var newList = new pList<T>(originalList);
```

To use an extension method, you have to make sure that the method is in scope.  I didn't add access modifiers to my example.  Put `internal` or `public` in, as appropriate:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    internal static pList<T> ToPList<T> //...
```

Also, if you want to use the extension method in a different namespace, you'll have to have a `using` directive in scope.  For example:

```
namespace A { public static class EnumerableExtensions { ...
```

Elsewhere:

```
using A;
// here you can use the extension method

namespace B
{
    public class C
    {
        ...
```

or

```
namespace B
{
    using A;
    // here you can use the extension method

    public class C
    {
        ...
```

Comment: Hello, my pList class does have a constructor that takes IEnumerable<T> have added your extension method but i am still unable to see ToPList() within the List<T> Am i missing something?

Comment: @JarmezDeLaRocha what do you mean by "within the `List<T>`"?  Do you mean in intellisense?

Comment: Yeah thats right, when i do list. i dont see for example toplist like i see tolist or toarray. Am i missing the point? I am just doing soem reading on these extension methods now they are new to me!

Comment: Your extension method class needs to be visible to where your code is that is using it, so you may need to add a `using` declaration.

Comment: Actually your solution did help me, the design was bad and actually i had never studied extension methods. The extension methods allowed me add the methods in i needed in pList without having to actually create a new sub class. Much appreciated for all the help! and everyone else who replied.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what you're intending to accomplish, but perhaps you could add the following code:

```
// Constructor which handles enumerations of items
public pList(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    // this.innerCollection = new Something(items);
}
```

Then with an extension method:

```
public static class pListExtensions
{
    public static pList<T> ToPList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return new pList<T>(items);
    }
}
```

Used later in your code:

```
var items = (from t in db.Table
             where condition(t)
             select new { Foo = bar(t), Frob = t.ToString() }).ToPList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also define an [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) cast.

```
public static implicit operator pList<T>(List<T> other)
{
     //Code returning a pList
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an extension method that returns your new list type

```
public static List<TSource> ToMyList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    return new pList<TSource>(source);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IList<T>` is an interface. Not a class. If you're treating your class as an instance of `IList<T>`, you can simply cast back rather than calling `ToList()`:

```
// assume you're working with IList<string> instance = new pList<string>()
pList<string> castedBack = (pList<string>)instance;
```